# How do I compile SQL email but not send?

Tags: sql-server, email, outlook, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

In **SQL Server**, it's possible to send an email via Outlook.

I want to compile an email but have it automatically sent. The code below automatically queues the email and sends to the recipients. I need to make adjustments on the email before sending it out. These adjustments account for dates. Is that possible?

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@profile_name = 'Email Team',
@recipients='username@eemail.com',
@subject='Monthly Report',
@body='Good morning, reports have ran for these dates: ',
@body_format='HTML',
@from_address='<username@email.com>'
```

As a result, I get this:

```
Mail (Id: 3549) queued.
```

Comment: check this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8288a3ff-f6d2-4bd2-99f9-406e812f1c40/spsenddbmail-queues-but-never-sends?forum=transactsql

Comment: *"In SQL Server, it's possible to send an email via Outlook."* You don't send it via Outlook; you connect to a mail server and that mail server sends it (that could be via IMAP, POP3, Exchange). Outlook is an application that connects to Mail Servers, it is not a mail server though.

Comment: If you don't want to send them immediately, you would be better to store the data in a table, and the loop (yes, I actually mean loop this time) through those rows and send each "queued" mail via `sp_send_dbmail`.